# Macro for entry loop causing 'null' variable template error

Tags: entries, category, loop, macro, null

I am new to the concept of Twig templates and I can’t get it right from the documentation … What I am trying to achieve is to have a reusable Blogroll snippet that outputs entries in different contexts: ALL entries on the homepage and then according to the entry’s category in other areas of the site.

I created a file `blogroll.html` in `templates/macros` containing my blogroll code which works fine if used directly in a template (simplified the HTML here):

```
{% macro blogroll(entry) %}
<a href="{{ entry.url }}">
  <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
</a>
{% endmacro %}
```

In my `index.html` for the homepage I try inserting it with this code:

```
<section class="blogroll">
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').limit(15).find() %}
{% for entry in entries %}
  {% import "macros/blogroll" as blogroll %}
  {{ blogroll.blogroll }}
{% endfor %}
</section>
```

In my category related templates I filter for the `category` first and try to insert it this way:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}
{% for entry in entries %}
  {% import "macros/blogroll" as blogroll %}
{{ blogroll.blogroll }}
{% endfor %}
```

In both cases I get a `Impossible to access an attribute ("url") on a null variable.` error though.

Any hints where I am not getting the concept right or screw something up while passing the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `blogroll` can be treated as a PHP function. In order to use functions you have to pass the required parameters. In your case your `blogroll` expects the parameter `entry`

```
{{ blogroll.blogroll(entry) }}
or
{{ blogroll.blogroll(category) }}
```

will work

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Seems like I was indeed simply missing that parameter.